# adding permission check on foreach loop on Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i think this question has been asked in many different ways but i cant find an exact answer to mine since i have very limited knowledge in Codeigniter.
the business case on this matter is that the user should only see the store that has permissions to view. however on the database the user table has (store_id) and the store table has (user-id). so the following code should bring the result  according to the user store_id on the current logged in user. but now it brings all the results since all sales users has the same role "sales".

```
     <?php foreach ($Stores as $store):?>
     <?php if($this->user->role === "sales"){?>  <a href="javascript:void(0)"  onclick="OpenRegister(<?=$store->status ? $store->status : 0;?>, <?=$store->id;?>)">
          <li class="listing clearfix">
            <div class="image_wrapper">
              <img src="<?=base_url()?>assets/img/store.svg" alt="store">
            </div>
            <div class="info">
              <span class="store_title"><?=$store->name;?></span>
              <span class="store_info"><?=$store->city;?> <span>&bull;</span> <?=$store->phone;?> <span>&bull;</span> <?=$store->email;?></span>
            </div>
            <span class="store_type <?= $store->status == 1 ? 'store_open' : 'store_close';?>"><?= $store->status == 1 ? label('open') : label('close');?></span>
          </li>
        </a><?php } ?>
        <?php endforeach;?>
```

appreciate your help

thank you

Comment: Side note: that is the wrong syntax for embedding an if statement in HTML you should be writing `<?php if () ; ?>` and <?php endif; ?>

Comment: And don't use <?= ?> php short tags (bad practice), always use <?php echo ''; ?>

Comment: noted jethro ,will keep that in mind thank you

Comment: Have you tried something like <?php if ($this->user->store_id === $store->store_id) : ?>

Comment: assuming store being the object of store type it will have id and $this->user->id will have user id you can check if($store->id==$this->user->id) should solve the problem...why you are only checking the roles..?

Comment: Right now you are looping through your `$Stores` array and not doing a check on any of your 'as $store' variables so of course you will see all your stores... you only want to display a store IF the store id matches the store id in the user table.

Comment: thank you very much awesome people it worked on this {($store->id==$this->user->store_id)}